# Congrats Keith C!

Tags: discussion

Congrats [Keith C](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/887/keith-c) with 100k reputation!

I can say personally, that I have found a lot of solutions of my sf problems from Keith's answers!

Thanks for your dedication!

Comment: And then there were three.

Comment: All good things come in threes

Comment: Including the more than 3,000 answers Keith has contributed! Congratulations and many thanks.

Comment: Ok, nobody else upvote those first two comments, but let's get another one to three so that the circle is complete. I'm also tempted to not upvote this meta any more (3 is good enough for us, yeah?)

Comment: Congrats Keith! well deserved!

Comment: @KeithC has helped me immeasurably over the years. One thing I really appreciated were his answers to VF PDF rendering issues; for those of you who don't know, he has an [informative blog](https://force201.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thanks all for this post and the comments!

This is a nice milestone to get to, and it only took 6 years. Which means if sfdcfox takes a few years off, I'm going to overtake him sometime in 2035...

The magic for me here is the other contributors - there are many - who share their tremendous breadth and depth of knowledge every day. They have saved me countless weeks of effort and added clarity about what is going on. And while posting an answer takes a bit of time, the answering process in itself is a learning experience, with the feel-good factor of helping both the individual who asked and the community in general.

**PS**

Come on now folks, I need an answer to [Does data referenced from the Platform Cache consume heap space?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268878/does-data-referenced-from-the-platform-cache-consume-heap-space) as otherwise, I'm actually going to have to do some work myself...

**PPS**

Question now answered by Renato Oliveira - thank-you for that.

Comment: Congrats Keith, Well deserved (y)

Comment: Congrats Keith you are an inspiration for all of us :) Keep rocking :+1:

Comment: Congratulations ! Very well deserved 

Comment: Well done! and thanks for all your help and contribution :)

Comment: Congrats Keith, Way to go!

Comment: Congrats Keith, that was a great contribution.

Comment: Congrats Keith, keep it up!